# How to prepare SOAP Request and call web service in java

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I am new to SOAP , I want to call web service .
I have seen a tutorial for making soap request .
This is the Code

```
    MessageFactory mf = null;
    SOAPMessage sm = null;
    SOAPEnvelope envelope = null;
    MimeHeaders headers = null;
    SOAPBody body = null;
    SOAPElement requestData = null;
    SOAPElement requestDoc = null;
    CDATASection cdata = null;
    SOAPConnectionFactory sfc = null;
    SOAPConnection connection = null;
    URL requestUrl = null;
    SOAPMessage response = null;
    OutputStream os = null;
    String host = null;
    int port = 80;
    String path = null;
    String api_key = null;
    int socket_timeout = 0;
    String service_type = null;
    String baseXml = null;

    try {

        xmlChannelRequest = createChannelRequest(cmId, function, guId, password, estabId);

        mf = MessageFactory.newInstance();
        sm = mf.createMessage();
        envelope = sm.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope();
        envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("soap", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
        envelope.setPrefix("soapenv");

        envelope.setAttribute("xmlns:tem", "http://tempuri.org/");

        headers = sm.getMimeHeaders();
        headers.addHeader("SOAPAction", "http://tempuri.org/IPublicChannelManagerService/RequestData");

        body = envelope.getBody();
        body.setPrefix("soapenv");

        requestData = body.addChildElement("RequestData");
        requestData.setPrefix("tem");

        requestDoc = requestData.addChildElement("requestDocument", "tem", "http://tempuri.org/");


     cdata = requestDoc.getOwnerDocument().createCDATASection("<Request>\n"
                + "           <Authentication CMId=\"6438\" Function=\"31\" Guid=\"5594FB83-F4D4-431F-B3C5-EA6D7ASDSBA795\" Password=\"y656g321TR\"/>\n"
                + "           <Establishment Id=\"297867\"/>\n"
                + "        </Request>");



        requestDoc.appendChild(cdata);

        System.out.println("----------------  SOAP Request ----------------------------");

        sm.writeTo(System.out);

        sfc = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
        connection = sfc.createConnection();
        requestUrl = new URL("http://pp.xxx.yyyy.co.uk/zzzz.svc?wsdl");

        response = connection.call(sm, requestUrl);
```

This is working fine. My question is , is there any easy way , just like passing object to method and it creates , SOAP request .
ex : **Just like JaxB , i will send a Bean , it will generate xml.**

```
        outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(beanObject, outputStream);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have the `WSDL` file before you make the *request*. Then just generate your specific classes using e.g. *wsimport* tool and then just call the *JAX-WS* webservice. You do not have to build the *request* by yourself in this way.

Have a look over [this](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-hello-world-example/) tutorial.